# Unexpected type error in websockets when compiling nest js project

Tags: websocket, nestjs

Below is my code

I tried to set a web socket gateway as below.

events.gateways.ts

```
import {
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from "@nestjs/websockets";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
})
export class EventsGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage("events")
  handleEvent(@MessageBody() data: string): string {
    return data;
  }
}
```

I set above gateway as a provider to a module.

events.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { EventsGateway } from "./events.gateway";

@Module({
  providers: [EventsGateway],
})
export class EventsModule {}
```

Fianllt, i imported above module to the app.module.ts and now I am getting the error

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { APP_FILTER } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AllExceptionFilter } from "./all-exception.filter";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Student } from "./student/entities/student.entity";
import { EventsModule } from "./events/events.module";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: "postgres",
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT as string) | 5432,
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      entities: [Student],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    EventsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: AllExceptionFilter,
    },
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is the error I am keep getting.

```
TypeError: this.graphInspector.insertEntrypointDefinition is not a function
    at /home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:108:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocketsController.inspectEntrypointDefinitions (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:106:25)
    at WebSocketsController.subscribeToServerEvents (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:39:14)
    at WebSocketsController.connectGatewayToServer (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:30:14)
    at SocketModule.connectGatewayToServer (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:47:35)
    at /home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:36:38
    at IteratorWithOperators.forEach (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/iterare/lib/iterate.js:157:13)
    at SocketModule.connectAllGateways (/home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:36:14)
    at /home/Desktop/New Folder/nest_try_1/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/socket-module.js:31:61

Node.js v19.4.0
```

I am follwing the documentation and I am keep getting above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should align your dependencies, ie., if you're using `@nestjs/websockets` v9.3.1, `@nestjs/core` must be in v9.3.1 as well

Run `npx nest info` and check that out.

That error is because `@nestjs/websockets` is invoking a method added in v9.3 which depends on a method added in v9.3 of `@nestjs/core` as well.

btw there are closed issues on GitHub about that error: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues?q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc+is%3Aclosed+insertEntrypointDefinition