# Nestjs cannot start server when gateway is initialized

Tags: typescript, sockets, nestjs

I have a working project with a ton of features using nestjs.
I want to make a connection via sockets. Following the tutorial, I am creating a gateway via `nest g resource` command and I put a handler inside

```
import { SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { SocketsService } from './sockets.service';

@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
export class SocketsGateway {
  constructor(private readonly socketsService: SocketsService) {}

  @SubscribeMessage('events')
  getTransactions(): string {
    return 'hello here';
  }
}
```

It is incredibly simple DEFAULT implementation just to test it. But after I do this the whole project dies (npm run start:dev) with the following error:

```
\node_modules\@nestjs\websockets\web-sockets-controller.js:106
        messageHandlers.forEach(handler => {
                        ^
TypeError: this.graphInspector.insertEntrypointDefinition is not a function
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: It seems like this is more related to websockets than normal sockets, is this true?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359149/ Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75360518/5290447